# Is there a fixed-point decimal object in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, fixed-point

In other languages, there is often a fixed decimal object that can be used in place of IEEE float/doubles, to help guarantee precision.  Does Objective-C have something similar?  When I was looking, all I found was NSNumber, which seems to only deal with the standard primitive types.  Is there another object I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`NSDecimalNumber`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) maybe?

According to [this post](http://webbuilders.wordpress.com/2009/04/12/objective-c-float-double-decimal/) there is a `Decimal` type that does not use IEEE floating point representation.

Comment: that seems to be more of an implementation of the IEEE standard in object form - unless I am missing something obvious?

Comment: @aperkins It actually wraps NSDecimal. It supports fixed-precision up to 38 decimal digits. See [this page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NumbersandValues/Articles/DecimalNumbers.html) for more information on NSDecimalNumber and NSDecimal.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw: How can it support fixed precision "up to" 38 digits after the radix point? It's either exactly 38 digits or it's a floating-point number.

Comment: As Sedate mentioned, this was my thought as well.

Comment: However, I just re-read the Decimal type again - that does seem to be closer to what I am looking for.  Thank you.